# Circle collision offset

Tags: circles, collision-detection

Just to clear some things

- i know how to detect collision
- i do not want a bounce effect since i am not working with velocity

so lets say i have 2 circles **C1** and **C2**. **C1** can not be moved, and is stationary. **C2** moves into **C1**. Therefore **C2** gets pushed back, but how do i calculate what **C2**'s new center points Coordinates should be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfjpH.png
so it is basically going from picture 2 to picture 3

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What exactly do you mean by "pushed back"?  What determines where the new center point "should" be?

Comment: It looks from the diagram that C2 isn’t necessarily moving directly toward C1’s center. Is that correct? Once they make contact, are you basically looking for the line along which C2 will be reflected?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be as follows:

Let $d $ denote the distance between the circle's centers and $r,R $ be the circles' radius.

If they are overlapping, $d < r + R $.

Draw a line connecting the two centers and slide the circles' centers, along that line, until $d = r + R $.

Depending on what you want, you may move just one of the circles by a distance of $r + R - d $, or both of them. If you move both, you could move both of them the same distance, or proportionally to (the inverse of) their size, for example.

Comment: i forgot to say that all this is in a 2D graph. so how can i calculate p2 new Coordinates?